# What is the term for a property instantiated either verbally or by judgement?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology

A promise is an example of a speech act. Is there a broader term encompassing nonverbal judgements? For example, consider a domain where objective measures of a property are vague or nonexistent; a thing has that property if it is deemed to have it by enough, or authoritative, members of the domain's community.

Comment: Are you asking if reality is constructed by social consensus in ways other than a verbal and articulate and performative speech act?

Comment: You need an example or two.

Comment: Consider the rubber/steel wheel schism amongst Mennonites. Though there are some rules for determining if rubber tires are kosher (pardon the term), ultimately it is a status conferred.

Comment: Can you write please an example of a "nonverbal judgement"?

Comment: [Vague](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/) or fuzzy property.

Comment: Nonverbal example might be the status as art conferred on an object when it is displayed in a museum - such as Duchamp's Readymades or the banana duct taped to a wall. I recall there being a term for conferred existence, but perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: A speech act may be non-verbal. A person bowing, or making a rude gesture, can be understood as performing an illocutionary act. The director of an art gallery taping a banana to a wall is thereby declaring this to be a work of art. If I did it, it would be a waste of a banana, but if the right person does it, it counts as an illocutionary act. A related concept is that of *fiat* - something that is made true because an appropriate authority says it is so.

Comment: Your post is unclear even after reading your comments. (1) Neither a promise is a judgment nor do promises and judgments are sets of some partition. Since promises and judgments are not comparable to each other, it is unclear how much you expect the "broader term" to encompass. (2) Vagueness and nonexistence preempt objectivity even where an authority outlines vague criteria. (3) The Mennonites and museum director examples certainly incorporate the authority component, but one can judge in a way that departs from authoritative sources. Should the "broader term" encompass also those judgments?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.